# discord.py статистика модератора

Tags: discord.py

Я хочу сделать статистику модерации, то есть, если модератор кикает нарушителя, то в его (модератора) профиль добавляется один кик, если ещё одного кикает, то ещё добавляется один кик и в итоге с двух киков, два очка кика в профиле модератора. В общем счётчик киков одного модератора. Пример на скрине ниже[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Записывайте данные в бд (например sqlite), а при выполнении команды выводите их в embed'е.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе понадобится библиотека jason. В краце создаёшь текстовый документ где будут хранится все параметры для каждого модератора по айди и потом выводишь их в сообщении.